# Take XML elements upwards and downwards from a certain node, but between certain elements only

Tags: xml, xpath

This is a simplified and cleaned (to the basics needed for the solution) version of the XML that I have to work on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<body>
    <p>
      <pPr>
        <section> <!-- section 1 -->
          Some data
        </section>
      </pPr>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="0" name="_GoBack"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="0"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="1" name="Reminder"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="1"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <pPr>
        <section> <!-- section 2 -->
          Some data
        </section>
      </pPr>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="2" name="Instruction"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="2"/>
    </p>
    <tbl>
        Some data
    </tbl>
    <p>
        <section> <!-- section 3 -->
          Some data
        </section>
    </p>
    <section> <!-- section 4 -->
      Some data
    </section>
</body>
```

I have only the name of of a bookmark, provided, so f.e. "Reminder". What I need to achieve is to get the `<p>` that contains the first section that happens to be above the node containing the bookmark with the given name + everything after that `<p>` until the **next** `<p>` which contains a `section`, but *without* that next `<p>`.

Maybe a bit of clearance on a sample logic:

1. Find the bookmark element with the given name provided as value of the `name` attribute
2. Find the first occurrence of `section` upwards from that bookmark and *select the section's parent + everything between it and the bookmark + the bookmark itself*
3. Find the first occurrence of `section` downwards from that bookmark and *select everything between the bookmark and the section's parent (but without the section's parent itself)*.
4. Get the 2 selections as one combined result.

So, if I am given "Reminder" (or "_GoBack") then I should get this:

```
    <p>
      <pPr>
        <section> <!-- section 1 -->
          Some data
        </section>
      </pPr>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="0" name="_GoBack"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="0"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="1" name="Reminder"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="1"/>
    </p>
```

If I am given "Instructions" then I should get this:

```
    <p>
      <pPr>
        <section> <!-- section 2 -->
          Some data
        </section>
      </pPr>
    </p>
    <p>
      <bookmarkStart id="2" name="Instruction"/>
      <bookmarkEnd id="2"/>
    </p>
    <tbl>
        Some data
    </tbl>
```

and so on, in case there are other bookmarks between *section 3* and *4*.

The most working code I've got so far is this:

```
//body/*[following-sibling::node()[self::*[descendant-or-self::bookmarkStart[@name="Instruction"]]] and preceding-sibling::*[*/section][2]] | //body/*[preceding-sibling::node()[self::*[descendant-or-self::bookmarkStart[@name="Instruction"]]] and following-sibling::*[*/section][1]]
```

But you can see that I am using hard-coded indexes (as in here: `[*/section][1]`) and I need it to be a dynamic solution...

I hope I explained it understandable enough.

Comment: Is there a requirement that this all be handled within a single XPath statement?  Are you in an XSLT process, or somewhere else?

Comment: @bjimba, it can be run in 2 steps (2 statements) as well.